# docker compose: what is the default 'command'?

Tags: docker, documentation

Docker noob here

[Reference for command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) says is it will 'Override the default command', but what is the default command?

I can't find it online, and I haven't found it in the docs

I'm guessing its the argument to the `CMD` in the image's Dockerfile, correct?

Answer (score 3):

The “default command” is whatever the image's Dockerfile specifies in `CMD`, correct.

Some references [here](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-8-overriding-your-dockerfiles-cmd) and [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/overriding-entrypoint-and-command-in-docker-compose-yml/38589).